# Trouble accessing pseudo element via typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey Im having some trouble here..

I have an element on my page which is a square and it has a a pseudo element of `:after` which is being used to create and pointing arrow.. now im trying to access this psuedo element within my angular application.. but Im getting this error

[image]

my code is as follows

app.component.ts

```
 // Declared variable
 const creativeTechnologyTopBox = 
 window.getComputedStyle(<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.about-us_creative-technology_top-box'), ':after');

 // Declared function
 function mouseEnter(squareName, topBoxName, translatePercentage) {
  squareName.style.transition = '0.5s';
  topBoxName.style.display = 'block';
  squareName.style.zIndex = '1';
  squareName.style.width = '100vw';
  squareName.style.transform = `translateX(${translatePercentage})`;
}

// Calling function
creativeTechnology.onmouseenter = function(){
  mouseEnter(creativeTechnologySquare, creativeTechnologyTopBox, '0');
};
```

HTML

```
 <div class="about-us_creative-technology">
            <div class="about-us_creative-technology_top-box">
                <div class="about-us_creative-technology_h1">
                        <h1>Creative<br>Technology</h1>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Mobile and Web Application Development</li>
                        <li>Product Development</li>
                        <li>Software Development and Management</li>
                        <li>Architecture and Design</li>
                        <li>Cloud Management, Strategy and Management</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="about-us_creative-technology_square">

            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
&_top-box{
        height: 25vw;
        position: relative;
        &:after {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            border-top-color: #F2F2F2;
            border-width: 25px;
            margin-left: -25px;
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
        }
    }
```

if I console log `topBoxName` I get

[image]

and then if I add `.getPropertyValue(display)` I get none when cosole logged so Ive been able to get that

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `getComputedStyle()`(The object returned from getComputedStyle is read-only) method (`IE < 9: currentStyle property`) corresponds to the rendered on-page style of an element after all stylesheets were applied. Setting style properties is done directly via the `style` property of an element:

Comment: yep, topBoxName.style is undefined

Comment: I think query selector is returning null

Comment: try without pseudo element

Comment: Theres no error when I remove window.getComputedStyle and the psuedo element but that doesnt matter because its the pseudo element im trying to target

Comment: can you share your html page and css

Comment: The getComputedStyle() method (IE < 9: currentStyle property) corresponds to the rendered on-page style of an element after all stylesheets were applied. Setting style properties is done directly via the style property of an element:

Comment: As @Dhaval answer `getComputedStyle` is read only we can not change the style

Comment: Yes I understand that Now I will have to do this another way

Answer (score 0):

According to docs [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The object returned from getComputedStyle is read-only and can be used
>   to inspect the element's style (including those set by a 
>   element or an external stylesheet). The element.style object should be
>   used to set styles on a specific element.